# Editing table layouts in jQuery

Tags: jquery, layout

So I'm building a CMS and for a given page, I want to let the client layout the page (not the site layout, the page layout, i.e. the content; headline, text, imageboxes, more links and such) with the given elements. Since table layouts are easy to understand for a client, I'm going to use that. Spare me the "always use CSS layouts" comments. I usually use CSS, but for this I really think a table layout is the best way to give the clients an easy to use environment.

So, the client should have a "edit layout" button, which takes them to a new page with the layout grid shown and all the content "modules" shown as boxes. They should be able to re-arrange the boxes and sort them inside the table cells at will. This is no problem for me, but I *ALSO* want the client to be able to edit the layout table itself.

They should be able to add a column, add a row, merge cells (horizontally) and adjust cell widths (not heights).

I've been googling a lot but most table jQuery plugins are about editing table DATA, not the table itself.

Anyone have a good suggestion on where to start?

Comment: just wonder, with so many open Source and free CMS out there, why creating a new one all over again? :-/

Comment: Probably because, at least I haven't seen a good cms that integrate seamlessly into an application. Yes, you can create widgets or modules for the cms, but when you have a ready application, you're on your own. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Or to learn... if the new generation of programmers just use third party libraries that we create - what do they do when we're gone?

Comment: Either way, the motive behind creating the CMS is irrelevant to the question. As far as I know, the above question isn't answered by "use this CMS instead", and even if it is, it's not a solution for me anyway. I started to build this CMS in 2001 and the landscape was pretty different back then.

Answer (score 3):

Just some short examples to get you started (with reservations to not having tested anything, but at least it would get you started)

You would of course have to have a way for the customer to know which row, cell and column to pick. I leave that to you, but a `$('table').click()` might work fine.

Copies the last table row and inserts it after the last:

```
$('#main-table-layout tr:last').after($('#main-table-layout tr:last').clone());
```

Inserts a new column into the table (creates a td in each of the rows)

```
$('#main-table-layout tr).each(function(){
  $(this).find('td:last').after($('<td></td>'));
});
```

Adjusting the cell-width, you do best with css:

```
$('#the-cell-that-you-want-to-change').css('width','500px');
```

To adjust the width on all cells:

```
$('td').css('width','500px');
```

Or to the 3rd column (3rd cell in each row)

```
$('tr').each(function(){$(this).find('td:eq(2)').css('width','500px')});
```

it might be possible to do the previous one as

```
$('tr').find('td:eq(2)').css('width','500px');
```

but I am not really sure how jQuery do the selecting there.

But, in the end I think you'll better off to let them use an editor like [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com) or something similiar. Saves you all the trouble of taking care of that yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the row/column adding code, I can totally work out of that. As for the width editing, I would more like a drag-style resizing of the columns, adjusting all at the same time.

Comment: Added some more examples for the width, so you'll see how to change it for several at the same time. But for the drag-style, I can't help you (don't have time to write up the examples), but have a look at jQuery UI, it have a resizable plugin that might help you (http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Resizable)